# Getting the inverse of a matrix with PyMel in Maya 2017

Tags: python, maya, matrix-inverse, pymel

I've been looking around in the PyMel docs but can't I get the inverse of a matrix from pymel.core.datatypes. My code is:

```
inverseM = orientationM*bindRotationM;
inverseM = inverseM.asMatrixInverse()
```

I just get the error:
Error: line 1: AttributeError: file S:\Maya_2017_DI\build\Release\runTime\Python\Lib\site-packages\maya\OpenMaya.py line 54: asMatrixInverse #

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `inverseM` is already a pymel matrix, you want `inverseM.inverse()`.  The doc is [here](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/pymel/generated/classes/pymel.core.datatypes/pymel.core.datatypes.Matrix.html).  Actually its [the same thing for an OpenMaya MMatrix too](http://docs.autodesk.com/MAYAUL/2014/ENU/Maya-API-Documentation/index.html?url=python-api/MMatrix.html,topicNumber=python_api_MMatrix_html813d4f55-55ba-445d-b612-72a381501d8f)

Comment: Hi, you were kinda right. I was using TransformationMatrices and when i used asInverseMatrix() on one i got a plain Matrix back. When i multiplied the Matrix with the other TransformationMatricies they turned into plain Matricies too and then later on i couldn't use asMatrixInverse() because they were not TransformationMatricies anymore.